# PHP to Smarty, displaying some nested Arrays

Tags: php, smarty, multidimensional-array

I'm having some issues displaying some nested array results in smarty... here's what I have:

`$searchResults` - an array, where each row is a result set.  No problem here.
`$searchResults[$row][users][]` - this is the nested array I created.  If users exist for this row of the search results, I want to display every user....

So, here we have my smarty code:

```
{section name=i loop=$searchResults}
  {section name=j loop=$searchResults[i].users}
     {$searchResults[i].users[j].firstName}
  {/section}
{/section}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work out for me... it displays the users results in a crazy fashion in my table, instead of being inside the same `<td></td>` where the section is placed inside.

**UPDATE - Using For Each, with more code...**

```
{section name=i loop=$searchResults}
     <tr>
        <td>{$searchResults[i].id}</td>
        <td>                        
           {if $searchResults[i].users}
              {foreach from=$searchResults[i].users item=user}
             {$user.firstName} {$user.lastName} <br>
              {/foreach}
           {/if}
        </td>
      </tr>
 {/section}
```

This displays a table like this:

```
ID  
ID  
ID  
        Bob Boberton
        John Appleton


        Chris Cooley

        Carl Agley
        Cynthia Nobody
```

When it should be like this:

```
ID  Bob Boberton
    John Appleton

ID  Chris Cooley

ID  Carl Agley
    Cynthia Nobody
```

Comment: Is that the *exact* smarty code?  What is crazy about the output?  With that loop it will print each username one after the other with no spaces or formatting.

Comment: the loop looks correct, but sometimes I've seen section behave oddly, can you reproduce it with the {foreach} tag?

Comment: @drew010 the "crazy" part is that all rows continue to display/print normally, and then i have many blank rows with only the looped data (1 per row).  It makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @Scuzzy - the foreach produces more expected results...so I'm getting there.  Let me update the question with more code.

Comment: Do a var_dump of your search results, I think your array of results is not correct.  It looks like when you have an id, you have no users, and when you have an array of users, you have no id.  So the arrays are not quite set up right.

Comment: @drew010 yea... you're right.  This array is insane looking.  Let me push through this for a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You could go further and use another `foreach` for the main loop. I've found them to be easier to read and find what the issue is.

```
{foreach from=$searchResults item=result}
    <tr>
        <td>{$result.id}</td>
        <td>
            {if $result.users}
                {foreach from=$result.users item=user}
                    {$user.firstName} {$user.lastName}<br/>
                {/foreach}
            {/if}
        </td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

That said, I could not reproduce your issue with how `$searchResults` was described; both your loop and mine worked the same in the end. Below is the array I was using.

```
$smarty->assign('searchResults', array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'users' => array(
            array(
                'firstName' => 'Bob',
                'lastName' => 'Boberton',
            ),
            array(
                'firstName' => 'John',
                'lastName' => 'Appleton',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 10,
        'users' => array(
            array(
                'firstName' => 'Chris',
                'lastName' => 'Cooley',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 100,
        'users' => array(
            array(
                'firstName' => 'Carl',
                'lastName' => 'Agley',
            ),
            array(
                'firstName' => 'Cynthia',
                'lastName' => 'Nobody',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```